# rbind.fill returning column of only "NA"

Tags: r, binding, rows, rbind

I am using the following code to take the difference between my time series in my "Signal" column and create a new column, "Activity", containing that. If the signal is stronger than X then a 1 will be produced in the new column and if weaker then a 0. As I am taking the difference between each value and the next, obviously will be left with one less row than the "Signal".

```
df$Signal <- as.numeric(df$Signal)
Activity <- ifelse(diff(df$Signal)>=4, 1, 0)
Activity <- as.data.frame(Activity)
df <- rbind.fill(df, Activity)
```

However, when I use rbind.fill it returns df with the new column "Activity" only containing "NA".

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me.  But I guess(just a guess since you don't create a reproducible example with an expected output) you want something like :

```
transform(df, Activity = c(0,ifelse(diff(Signal)>=4, 1, 0)))
```